# Dual .htaccess: $_GET variable empties. What can I do?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am currently working on a project in which my Apache documentroot differs from the public directory in which my index.php resides. Strangely, due to this setup, my $_GET superglobal seems to be emptied.

**Directory structure:**

- /Documentroot
- /Documentroot/.htaccess

  - /public/.htaccess
  - /public/index.php

Things go wrong after the first .htaccess is processed.

```
#First .htaccess in Apache documentroot:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.+) public/$1 [NC,L]

# Second .htaccess in /documentroot/public:
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV testing
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

**Some observations:**

- When removing the primary .htaccess and placing an additional index.php in the documentoot, my $_GET variables show fine
- When dumping $_GET in the /public/index.php file, it is empty
- When calling index.php like /?foo=bar, $_GET is empty
- When calling index.php like /index.php?foo=bar $_GET is populated

**What could be causing the $_GET variable to be emptied?** Any help is appreciated.

***EDIT: things just got a whole lot stranger:***

When I leave both .htaccess files intact and place an index.php (or any index.* for that matter) file (no matter what content) in the documentroot, the index.php file in the /public directory is parsed and the $_GET variable is properly populated.

Comment: Probably not the issue, but are you sure you don't have an `index.htm` or other similar file in the document root? Try adding `DirectoryIndex index.php` to your `.htaccess`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I'm really sure that is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here, but when requesting `/?foo=bar`, The regex (.+) may be trying to match against the empty string, which fails the test.  Try changing it to (.*).

Edit: Actually, on second thought, when requesting `/?foo=bar`, if it matches "/", then it rewrites to `public//`, which will get rewritten to `index.php` by your last rule.  Maybe try `^/?(.*)$` as your first pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what's happening:

1. You request `/?foo=bar`
2. `RewriteRule` in `documentroot/.htaccess` redirects to `public/?foo=bar`
3. In `public/.htaccess`, the `RewriteCond`s check whether it is a file, a symlink, or a directory. The string `/?foo=bar` is none of those, so the first `RewriteRule` is skipped.
4. `RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC, L]` is run. This directs all to `index.php` -- which is a URL without any $_GET variables. That's why they're disappearing.

You need to pass those GET variables in that last `RewriteRule`.

Comment: I have actually tried adding the QSA flag to the rewriterule, but this does not work. This is not the problem.